# Is there a generally acceptable definition of (soft) realtime delays?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, human-computer-interface

I'm trying to find a benchmark for how long users are willing to wait for a response from a remote service. In my case the response is for very useful but not business critical validation of data entry. I guess that there must have been some work done in the HCI space on this.

If you know of a generally accepted definition for **soft** realtime responses then great but I'd also appreciate your well reasoned thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

US DOD MIL-STD 1472-F Human Engineering Standard has the most widely accepted requirements for maximum allowed response time (from Table XXII, page 196, times in seconds):

Key Response (Key depression until positive response, e.g., "click"): 0.1

Key Print (Key depression until appearance of character): 0.2

Page Turn (End of request until first few lines are visible): 1.0

Page Scan (End of request until text begins to scroll): 0.5

XY Entry (From selection of field until visual verification): 0.2

Function (From selection of command until response): 2.0

Pointing (From input of point to display point): 0.2

Sketching (From input of point to display of line): 0.2

Local Update (Change to image using local data base, e.g., new menu list): 0.5

Host Update (from display buffer): 2.0

File Update (Change where data is at host in readily accessible form): 10.0

Inquiry - Simple (e.g., a scale change of existing image): 2.0

Inquiry - Complex (Image update requires an access to a host file): 10.0

Error Feedback (From command until display of a commonly used message): 2.0

As you can see, acceptable response time depends on what response the user is waiting for. For something like a pulldown menu appearing, it's 0.5 seconds max. For a full page load in a browser, you want something to appear in 1.0 s to 2.0 s and the full page loaded in 10.0 s. In all the above, shorter response times are better. Only in bizarre circumstances will users object to a 0.001s response time.

In any case, if the response time will be greater than 0.5 s, then you need to provide feedback such as a throbber or hourglass sprite. If response time is a minimum of 5-15 s (depending on what standard you use), provide a progress bar. With a progress bar, very long response times (on the order or minutes over even hours) may be acceptable as long as you set it up for the user as a “batch” process rather than being an interactive program. It's much better for the user to make all input and wait an hour than to make input on four occasions, waiting 15 minutes after each.

The above list has the accepted standards. How long your users are *willing* to wait (e.g., before giving up) essentially boils down to the user making a cost-benefit analysis. Is what I’m going to get worth the wait? What are my sunk costs? Is there an alternative (e.g., another web site) that can do it better? Can I do other things while I wait to make the most of my time? However, whatever users willing to do, you can bet they’ll resent delays greater than the standards above.

Comment: I guess that for web-based applications, the standard browser progress mechanism (spinning globe etc) would not be sufficient indication of progress.

Comment: I would consider the browser throbber sufficient feedback for response delays of up 15 s (barely). Seeing the page fill with content over 5+ seconds also provides a legitimate progress indication.

Answer (score 1):

Human reaction time seems to be around [200 ms](http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime/stats.php) - anything around there will be perceived as instantaneous. That sort of number is hard to achieve, especially in an application that gets information from remote services.

If you take a look at Google's search suggestion box, the lag there is minimal - less than a second. It's astoundingly fast, and really remarkable for a web application. This is really nice for Google's users, but it's bad news for you. These days, users expect most applications to react with the same sort of speed an efficiency; anything slower is considered rather laggy. However, it's worth noting that people's patience usually varies with the complexity of the task at hand. A simple form submit should never take much time, but something like uploading photos is expected to take a while.

My feeling is this: go with your gut. If your application is fairly simple then you should try to get the wait/load time down to less than a second. If you can't, then your best bet is to add an indicator so the user knows that some computations are being done in the background. This can be in the form of a small animation or a progress bar.

Comment: Thanks. As an aside, 200ms wouldn't be achievable, round-trip netowrk latency could easily swamp this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is not typically a well-defined number.  Users expectations vary widely and can change depending on what it is you're talking about.

As computers continue to become more ubiquitous and we (the consumers) continue to have growing expectations of speed, remote services, websites, and even applications will need to continue to respond more quickly.  Generally speaking, you want everything to be as fast as possible.

With this said, I would look at what your remote service is for.  Since you said, "the response is for very useful..." to me, that means it probably will get used frequently.  People tend to use what is useful.  If that's the case, I would look for ways to make that remote service respond quickly.

Of course, there is also the caveat that you don't want to start optimizing before the service is written. What is the current response time?  What is the context in which this will be used?  Those factors will do a lot to determine the longest users are willing to wait for the service.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for **"SLA"** or **"Service Level Agreement"**.  Those are the documents in a web business that make guarantees as to how long data will take to get back to the user, whether it's an HTML document or a web service call.